# VBA - Passing CustomerID into Enquiry Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using an On-click method on a button to pass the following

```
Private Sub cmdNewEnquiry_Click()
Call Command29_Click
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblEnquiry(CustomerID) Values('" & CustomerID & "')"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEnquiry", acNormal, , "CustomerID = " & CustomerID
End Sub
```

But whenever it passes the CustomerID into the next form, EnquiryID isn't the newest it could be maybe it shows a record that's 1 before this one. I'm then having to click through the records to find the newest Enquiry.

Is there a way I can pass this data through and make sure it displays the most up-to-date record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the RecordSource query in the form "frmEnquiry" by ordering the data for newest first. Or use the property field OrderBy in the form "frmEnquiry". Not knowing the query-fields of "frmEnquiry", I can not give you a more precise answer.

The part `"CustomerID = " & CustomerID` in the `doCmd.OpenForm` sets a filter for this CustomerID, but does not order anything.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I set OrderBy to EnquiryID DESC and its showing the newest enquiries. That just filters the enquiries to only that customer